# MongoDB - How to query array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with a (multi-level) nested array like this:

```
{ _id: "1", metadata: { parent: { tags: ['foo', 'bar'] } } }
{ _id: "2", metadata: { parent: { tags: ['foo'] } } }
{ _id: "3", metadata: { parent: { tags: ['bar'] } } }
```

I would like to query records matching parent's tags containing keywords like `foo`:

```
{ _id: "1", metadata: { parent: { tags: ['foo', 'bar'] } } }
{ _id: "2", metadata: { parent: { tags: ['foo'] } } }
```

How to write MongoDB query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieve with [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
db.collection.find({
  "metadata.parent.tags": "foo"
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xWNMHHZ5Y-S)